# Squid/DansGuardian: Block tls on specific websites

Tags: proxy, squid, https, tls, dansguardian

I have successfully set up squid in combination with DansGuardian and it blocks http-traffic really wel. Sadly (and understandable) it doesn't block https at all. Is there a way to:

- filter specific websites with an self-signed certificate
- forward to the http-version of specific websites (self-signed certificate?)
- block tls-encryption at all on specific websites

All traffic which doesn't use the proxy should be untouched.